# Stop Less Than Symbol Beginning New Line in Pre-Tagged Text

Tags: html, pre

I have already posted this here [here](http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/stop-less-than-symbol-beginning-new-line-in-pre-tagged-text?replies=1#post-2016274), and will notify this forum immediately of any developments there, though in the mean time I would very much appreciate some help.

Apologies also if I have not tagged this question correctly here.

I am using some code I found on another site so that I can wrap my text inside pre-tags for posts I make on my blog. I have it nearly all as I want apart from the fact that I cannot get it to NOT begin a new line at every occurrence of a less-than symbol.

I will try to past the code below but I imagine it may be affected by the editor so apologies in advance.

Many thanks

```
<pre style="white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;">=IF(ROWS(G$1:G1)&gt;$F$1,"",INDIRECT(TEXT(SMALL(IF(TRANSPOSE($A$1:$D$6)&lt;&gt;"",TRANSPOSE(10^(4+COLUMN($A$1:$D$6))*ROW($A$1:$D$6)+COLUMN($A$1:$D$6))),ROWS(G$1:G1)),"R0C"&amp;REPT(0,LEN(SMALL(IF(TRANSPOSE($A$1:$D$6)&lt;&gt;"",TRANSPOSE(10^(4+COLUMN($A$1:$D$6))*ROW($A$1:$D$6)+COLUMN($A$1:$D$6))),ROWS(G$1:G1)))-1)),0))</pre>
```

Comment: Do you really mean the character `<`, or the HTML entity `&lt;`? Because I don't see the former in your code above, other than in the HTML tags.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Whenever I use the less-than (and greater-than) symbol, even when I have pre-tags wrapped around the text, the editor in my Wordpress blog changes them all to that HTML entity.

Comment: Sincere apologies. That last comment is not strictly true. If I enter the less-than and greater-symbols as characters in the VISUAL editor, then they are converted to the HTML entities when I switch to the HTML editor. However, if I try to enter them as characters in the HTML editor, then they are simply not present in the end-result.

Comment: If I remove all the wrap stuff and just use pre-tags then the less-than and greater-than symbols appear fine.
But of course this is just in one long line and goes off the end of the page, which is why I'm trying to wrap it as well.
Maybe I can't have both?